# How to correct make binning

Tags: binning

I have a question regarding how to make binning correctly.

I have 500 rows with different values (wages) which vary a lot. For example: in row number 20 the wage is \$600, whereas in 40 the wage is \$50000.

Comment: Could you explain what the intended purpose of binning these wages might be?  We have little basis to answer this question in the absence of this needed context, for otherwise the understanding of "correct" will be contextual and subjective.

Comment: I just need to explore the data and make binning. Based on what can I do it?